# Combining JP2 images into a single image

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.3, jpeg-2000

I'm trying to merge multiple JP2 files into a single image to manipulate.

How do I do this?

There images are overlapping and next to each other, the data is HiRISE observations from Mars.

I've tried, Mosaic to new raster and other options, when I try to put an output function in the box but it tells me 'the object named ..... cannot be found' and will not let me complete the function.

Comment: The images are next to each other with some overlapping, Its HiRISE data of Olympus Mons

Comment: Using merge in arcmap isn't a good job. So, if you have any other image processing program like ENVI, or ERDAS, that will do that better. Just my opinion.

Comment: @PROBERT for producing a mosaic you do not want to use merge. The mosaic to new raster is the function for performing the task the OP is after. The merge function is meant for combining overlapping rasters with nominal data to produce a raster of unique combinations.

Comment: What have you already tried and what specifically are you having problems with?

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at this Technical Support [How To: Merge rasters using ArcGIS 8.x Spatial Analyst](http://support.esri.com/technical-article/000004687)

You might want to add more information to your question too. Whether the images are adjacent to each other or there are overlaps etc

The [Mosaic To New Raster](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/mosaic-to-new-raster.htm) help page should explain what you need to do.

Comment: I've tried to follow the article and I can't find the extent tab.

Comment: Mosaic To New Raster (Data Management) is the tool you want to use.  Below is the description from ArcMap.
Summary

Merges multiple raster datasets into a new raster dataset.

Comment: Search for the tool (Mosaic To New Raster) in the system tool boxes inside ArcMap.  Be sure to read this article to understand what is happening!

Comment: http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/mosaic-to-new-raster.htm